# Detect focus of window in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe

I have been building an app in Adobe AIR using HTML/JavaScript.

The windows are all Chromeless and use CSS to style them to look like an application.

How can I detect if the window is focused by the user so I can alter the colours of the windows in the same way that native windows have more subtle shadows etc.

An example might be:

```
var active = false;

$(document).ready(function() {

                active = nativeWindow.active;

                if(active) {
                    $('body').addClass('active');
                } else {
                    $('body').removeClass('active');
                }

});
```

But how do I properly handle the change of active event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with: air.NativeWindow.active. See: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/display/NativeWindow.html#active

**UPDATE**:

```
window.nativeWindow.addEventListener(air.Event.ACTIVATE, function() {
    $('body').addClass('active');
});

window.nativeWindow.addEventListener(air.Event.DEACTIVATE, function() {
    $('body').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Let's say I wanted to add a class of active to the body of the document if the window is active or not. How would I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Do you use JQuery or something like that?

Comment: The issue is getting the code inside the if statement to be called whenever the active state changes. At the moment it only happens on the document load.

Comment: Edited my Answer. Now there two event listeners for window if it is active or not.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot something - must be window.nativeWindow not only window and air.Event not only Event. Updated my code.